# How can I use switch button to set value to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

Please how can i achieve this!
I have a switch button i'll like to use to control boolean value (`true`/`false`) in my MongoDB database

```js
isBanned: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: false,
},
```

my  button

```html
<b-form-checkbox
  v-model="post.isBanned"
  switch
  @change="isBannedUser($event, post._id)"
>
  {{ post.isBanned }})
</b-form-checkbox>
```

What I expect to happen!
If I toggle the switch checkbox from the frontend (Nuxt), I want `isbanned` to be set to `true` and change the default `false` value in database. If I toggle the same checkbox again next time, I want `false` value to be sent to the backend and change the db value from `true` to `false` and vice versa

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      post: {
        isBanned: null,
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async isBannedUser(e, id) {
      const data = {
        isBanned: this.post.isBanned,
      }
      try {
        const response = await this.$axios.$patch(`/api/v1/posts/${id}`, data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

and my API

```js
router.patch('/posts/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const banned = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
    res.status(201).json({ banned })
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: do you have any error logs, network activity anything else you can provide? what is the issue here?

Comment: When I toggle the button, I expect the default false value I have in my database to change to true, and if true, it should change to false but nothing is happening. From my dev tool - component, when I toogle the value changes from false to true but the true/false value is not being sent to backend. The isBannedUser method returned success and no error.

Comment: Check your network so, is the request sent to the backend?

Comment: From the network, the request was sent to the backend but the value didn't change from true to false or false to true

Comment: What do you have on the backend? Is it receiving what you expect there?

Comment: I have a (req.body) in the backend

Comment: Yep, does it contain the actual data that you want? Can you make the update to the database? Is this one working there?

Comment: No, it's not receiving the data. However I have another button in a modal that sends data to the same API and it is recieving the data.

Comment: Focus on one thing at a time please. Why is it not receiving the actual payload on the backend? It's not sending the data properly? Double check with your browser devtools (network tab), why this is not passing it to the backend.

Comment: Alright, I'll double check. Can you take a look at my check button. Is that the right way to do it. Like, do I need to bind a value to it or something. Thanks

Comment: I formatted your code to have something more readable. By the looks of it, I guess it should work well (`v-model` is already binding the state) but I don't really work with Bootstrap. Debug from the frontend to the backend with all the tools that you can have: `vue devtools` to inspect the actual state in your UI, `browser devtools` (network tab) to see what you're actually sending to your database, then check your backend to see if you have anything in your router/controller/MongoDB.

Comment: I realized that whatever value is set in the data (){isBanned: true } is sent to the backend when I toggle. And when I toggle again I want it to send false value back to the backend but that not happening. Like, when clicked if value true, change to false and if false, change to true. On and off switch sort of

Comment: Hm, this doesn't really help me. What is not working exactly? Did you followed some steps as suggested above? Do you maybe have a [repro]?

Comment: The default state of the button is false, and I want it to perform 2 actions. Send true to the backend when I turn it on, then send false to the backend when I turn it off. But right now it sends true value to bckend when I turn it on and doesn't send false value when I turn it off.

Comment: So, let's focus on the first round trip. Do you have `true` from the start (UI) to your database done properly?

Comment: Yes, true was sent

Comment: If it was properly received and set in the database, you can probably sent it back to the front-end as a response. Or do you want no confirmation regarding the backend state change at all? If it works once, the toggle should work twice.